# Link Multiple AWS S3 Buckets to One Subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, subdomain

I have several AWS S3 buckets that I'd like to mask under one subdomain.

> **S3 Buckets**: Bucket A, Bucket B, Bucket C
>
> **Subdomain**: content.website.com

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How would you envision that working? How would S3 know which bucket to use for a particular request? Why not `content-a.example.com`, `content-b.example.com`, etc.?

Comment: I have 20+ buckets :-/

Comment: Just an assumption here, but he probably wants to reference "bucket-a" like so: http://content.website.com/bucket-a. That's how I came here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you write your own php script to issue redirects to the appropriate bucket based on the request uri. As an illustration you can setup paths like

content.website.com/a -> redirect to http://bucket-a.s3.amazonaws.com/
content.website.com/b -> redirect to http://bucket-b.s3.amazonaws.com/
...

If you need some help with the scripting let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like Apache HTTPD to host the subdomain, you could just create a bunch of RewriteRules to take a HTTP request to content.website.com and redirect to your S3 bucket. This assumes that the S3 bucket is publicly available. For example (based on user3697476's example):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule a/(.*) https://bucket-a.s3.amazonaws.com/$1 [R]
RewriteRule b/(.*) https://bucket-b.s3.amazonaws.com/$1 [R]
```

etc.

If your S3 buckets aren't publically accessible, you'd have to write some sort of proxy to download the item from S3 and serve that up to the user.